# JAX-WS: Generate XSD with nested (inner) types

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, jax-ws, inner-classes

I'm trying to make my JAX-WS web service to generate XSD with inner type. For example I have WS method that returns Foo type:

Foo.java

```
public class Foo {

    @XmlElement(name = "type")
    private NestedType type;

    public NestedType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(NestedType value) {
        this.type = value;
    }

    public Foo() {
    }

    public static class NestedType {

        @XmlElement(name = "name")
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

This generates the following XSD snippet:

```
<xs:complexType name="Foo">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="type" type="tns:NestedType" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="NestedType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

and produces standalone NestedType class with wsimport utility.
The thing I need is to have somthing like the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="Foo">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="type" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType name="NestedType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

to have wsimport generated NestedType inside Foo class.

Comment: Try to generate the java class from your XSD. Maybe you could use XJC. I think that missing only `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "name"
    })` on your inner class. Let me know.

Comment: It works! name="" did the trick!

Comment: is not a trick .. the inner type by XSD hasn't the name attribute.